# Unable to analyse how this output came for this code snippet

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I am unable to analyse how this output came for this code snippet:

```
l=[]

for i in range(1,9,2):   
            
           l.insert(i,i)

print(l)
```

```
output: [1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 7, 3, 5, 4, 7]
```

Please explain this code snippet.

Comment: That code does not produce that output.

Answer (score 1):

Well `l=[]` is an empty list for one. The second line is a `for` loop. The `range(1,9,2)` mean that it ranges from 1 to 9 but not including number 9. So it would be 8. The last number 2 means it is incremented by 2. The `insert()` function means that it inserts a `element` at a certain `index` in the list.

However, you do *not* get the specified output that you put in your question.

Comment: I have got that same output.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters passed in range function are *start*, *stop*, *step*. It means that we have the range from *start* to *stop* and at every iteration, we increment by *step*.
So,

```
for i in range(1, 9, 2):
```

means, that we ierate from 1 to 9 and increment by 2 at every step. It means, *i* will have values as: 1, 3, 5, 7

Now,

```
l.insert(i, i)
```

means that insert value *i* at index *i*. The insert function takes arguments as:

```
insert(index, value)
```

It inserts the *value* at *index*